# access other properties of a databound repeater in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater bound to a datasource, in the itemtemplate for the repeater i have a link button

im using stuff like:

<%# Eval("myfield") %>

to get data for the item.

i need a linkbutton in there that when clicked I can access all the properties relevant to that item in the onclick event handler in the backend.

how do i access the other properties of a paticular item, when a button within the itemtemplate is clicked.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

Pass the ID of the object as a CommandArgument, then reload it in the code behind

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnCommand="MyButton_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MyObjectId") %>'/>

protected void MyButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int myId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    // Load the object using the id passed in
}
```

or

Cast "sender" to the LinkButton, which will give you access to the RepeaterItem and any other controls in there 
...*violently throws up at the thought of even suggesting it*